# Expression Type 'Set<NSObject>' is ambiguous without more Context

Tags: swift, swift3, nsobject

I recently switched to Swift 3 and I got an error with the following line that I didn't get in swift 2. The layerClient call refers to the layerkit api, but the error seems to deal more with typing than the api. The error itself is "Expression Type 'Set' is ambiguous without more ".

```
layerClient.autodownloadMIMETypes = Set<NSObject>(arrayLiteral: "image/png")
```

Comment: You're passing it a string, not an array literal. Just surround it with [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using [this framework](https://github.com/layerhq/releases-ios).

You don't need the `<NSObject>` when creating the `Set`. It can figure out with type it contains by the parameter you pass to the init method. Also `autodownloadMIMETypes` type in swift would be `Set<String>` which wouldnt match `Set<NSObject>`. This should work.

```
layerClient.autodownloadMIMETypes = Set(arrayLiteral: "image/png")
```

Also, since `Set` conforms to the `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` protocol, you should be able to just create it like an array.

```
layerClient.autodownloadMIMETypes = ["image/png"]
```